# Good Material/Tutorial of Database Normalization

Tags: database, database-normalization

Does anyone have an idea on where I could get refined notes on Normalization of database tables(relations)?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is a pretty good start.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article posted by butterchicken is good; you might also find [this](http://www.datamodel.org/NormalizationRules.html) useful.

Comment: Awesome, bookmarked for future reference. +1

Comment: The link you referenced appears to be dead.